# How to convert dictionary to NSDictionary ios C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a dictionary of type Dictionary(Enum,CustomClass)

since i need to post notification and pass the dictionary values i need to use NSDictionary instead of dictionary of C#.
How do i convert this? if i use the following solution, it gives me an error
[Xamarin.iOS, convert Dictionary to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027542/xamarin-ios-convert-dictionary-to-nsdictionary)

Cannot convert enumtype to NSObject
     NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(notificationame,null,nsdictionary object);

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/a/5679603/6741868/?

Comment: share your dictionary code and code where you convert the dictionary to NSDictionary