# Getting validateMenuItem: to fire for NSMenuItem using Xamarin-generated action

Tags: c#, xcode, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I would like to add additional menu items to my context menu. Ideally the items are enabled using validateMenuItem:

```
    [Action("validateMenuItem:")]
    public bool ValidateMenuItem(NSMenuItem item)
    {
        _logger.DebugFormat("Validating {0} menu item with Action {1}", item.Title, item.Action.Name);
        var target = item.Target;
        var menuItem = ViewModel.ContextMenu.Where(x => x.Title == item.Title).FirstOrDefault();
        if (menuItem != null) {
            return menuItem.Command.CanExecute();
        }

        return false; 
    }
```

per https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html. If I manually create an action this gets called, but if I assign an eventhandler like so:

```
            var nsMenuItem = new NSMenuItem(menuItem.Title,
                                            (sender, e) =>
            {
                menuItem.Command.ExecuteAsync();
            });
            nsMenuItem.Target = this;
```

validateMenuItem: does not get called. The Action that is assigned using this method is __monomac_internal_ActionDispatcher_activated: from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/AppKit/ActionDispatcher.cs (help me please Rolf Bjarne Kvinge). Since I do not have this action in my class (I think), validateMenuItem is never called and my menu item is never activated. How can I make this work?

**Update.** If I add this to my view controller,

```
    [Action("__monomac_internal_ActionDispatcher_activated:")]
    public void MonomacInternalAction(NSObject sender)
    {
    }
```

validateMenuItem: gets called for the new items. However, the event handler is replaced by this function. (This problem might not be solvable!) This might be an Export vs Action issue - I see

```
    const string skey = "__monomac_internal_ActionDispatcher_activated:";

    [Preserve, Export (skey)]
    public void OnActivated (NSObject sender)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Activated;
        if (handler != null)
            handler (sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

*Update 2.* just found https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51343

**Update 3.** I can cheat the validateMenuItem by using

```
    public override bool RespondsToSelector(ObjCRuntime.Selector sel)
    {
        if (sel.Name.Contains("__monomac_internal_ActionDispatcher_activated")) {
            return true;
        }
        return base.RespondsToSelector(sel);
    }
```

now if I could only find a way of calling the original event!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a bug in the Xamarin.Mac implementation - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51343. I ended up with a workaround. Instead of using an eventhandler or a separate action for each menu item (couldn't figure out how to register), I created a single action to handle all menu items.

```
    [Action("contextAction:")]
    public void contextAction(NSObject sender)
    {
        if (sender is NSMenuItem)
        {
            var nsMenuItem = (NSMenuItem)sender;
            var wrapper = nsMenuItem.RepresentedObject as NSObjectWrapper;
            if (wrapper != null) {
                var menuItem = wrapper.Context as MenuItem;
                if (menuItem != null) {
                    menuItem.Command.ExecuteAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then

```
        foreach (var menuItem in ViewModel.ContextMenu)
        {
            var selector = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("contextAction:");
            var nsMenuItem = new NSMenuItem(menuItem.Title, selector, "");
            nsMenuItem.RepresentedObject = new NSObjectWrapper(menuItem);
```

NSObjectWrapper comes from [Monotouch: convert an Object to NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664321/monotouch-convert-an-object-to-nsobject).